# "NULL" instead of null values in PySpark

Tags: python, string, dataframe, pyspark, double

I have a dataframe df, but because 3 of its columns that should normally be "double" have values like "NULL", the automatic type is cast as string.

```
df =

col_0      col_1      col_2            col_3
Word       73452     3859.0     4734.0000000
Word1      23452     3859.0             NULL
Word2      73452       NULL     4758.0000000
Word1      73454       NULL     4756.0000000
Word2      73452     3456.0     4758.0000000
```

I want to change this and my attempt was:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

def my_function(df):
    df_1 = df.withColumn("col_1", df["col_1"].cast(DoubleType()))
    df_2 = df_1.withColumn("col_2", df_1["col_2"].cast(DoubleType()))
    df_3 = df_2.withColumn("col_3", df_2["col_3"].cast(DoubleType()))
    return df_3
```

But I don't know how to replace the string "NULL" with an empty kind of null. And even so, would that be enough?

Comment: What is `NULL` above? Is it text?

Comment: I tested it - `.cast(DoubleType())` replaces every non-double convertible entry to empty kind of null you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and replacing the strings with value `NULL` with the Python's `None` type and then casting to correct types, like this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Word1", 23452, 3859.0, "NULL"), ("Word2", 73452, "NULL", 4758.0000000)], "col_0: string, col_1: int, col_2: string, col_3: string")
print(df.dtypes)

# [('col_0', 'string'), ('col_1', 'int'), ('col_2', 'string'), ('col_3', 'string')]

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

print(df.na.replace("NULL", None).select(col("col_0"), col("col_1").cast("int"), col("col_2").cast("double"), col("col_3").cast("double")).dtypes)

# [('col_0', 'string'), ('col_1', 'int'), ('col_2', 'double'), ('col_3', 'double')]
```